# Sheaf cohomology in the classical setting, carrying it over to the étale setting?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, arithmetic-geometry

There is a road map for learning arithmetic algebraic geometry by Matthew Emerton [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/bin/emerton-roadmap.pdf). Consider the following paragraph.

> What *is* worthwhile, is to get a good understanding of sheaf cohomology in the classical setting. (The beginning of Borel's book on intersection homology which ultimately is about perverse sheaves and so on, but which begins with background on constructible sheaves and Grothendieck’s six operations, is one place to do this.) The point is that most applications of étale cohomology use just the same sheaf theoretic formalism as one has in the classical setting (i.e. varieties over the complexes, with their complex topology), and the main technical theorems in the subject (proper base-change, smooth acyclicity, nearby and vanishing cycles) are precisely intended to show that étale cohomology, étale constructible sheaves, and Grothendieck’s six operations in the étale setting, behave exactly as they do in the classical setting. So if one has a good understanding of sheaves in the classical setting, you can be confident that your intuition there will carry over to the étale setting.

Is it possible anybody could expand somewhat on the contents of this paragraph?

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you want expanded? Whenever someone gives you a question in etale cohomology I think the thinking goes as follows a) think about what happens in the topological analogue of your problem, b) give a rough sketch of the proof there using 'topological sheaf cohomology techniques', and then c) use the wonderful formalism of etale cohomology which is constructed so that (of course, with necessary modifications) your topological argument should 'go through' in the etale case. I think this last step that things are set-up in a way so that topological arguments

Comment: 'go through' is the point of Matt E's comment (of course, I'm not Matt E, so I can't say for sure). Of course, this can only get you so far, and computing things which are 'obvious' topologically can sometimes be painful precisely because the technical details of 'it goes through' can sometimes be immense. As an example of this one should think about the following classic computation. Let $k=\mathbb{Q}$, let $j$ be the inclusion of $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$, and $i$ the inclusion of the origin into $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$

Comment: Try computing $i^\ast R^m j_\ast\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ as a representation $\rho:G_\mathbb{Q}\to\text{GL}_k(\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$. It's obvious what the answer should be topologically, and that IS what happens in the etale case (thanks again to the beautiful technological setup of etale cohomology to make such things happen) but the justification is certainly semi-non-trivial.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I haven't read Borel's book or say Kashiwara-Schapira in depth, so I'm interested in a summary of "working intuition/knowledge" for sheaf cohomology in the classical setting, and perhaps a longer elaboration on how to carry it over to the étale setting than what is present in Emerton's roadmap. Also, if you are willing to give a quick sketch of the two computations you mentioned above in an answer, it would probably benefit future algebraic number theorists and arithmetic geometers tremendously. No worries if not, though.

Comment: That's an immense amount to summarize, I think. Perhaps a good place to start would be to understand the statement of (not proof, although it's not too hard) and applications of proper base change in classical topology. Perhaps also understanding what goes wrong there if your map is not proper and how to fix it (all of this between, say, manifolds). Also, having a good topological picture as to what $f_\ast,f_!,f^!$... do topologically is important I think. I don't know if I can reasonable summarize all of this now--perhaps someone with a more deft hand can. Also, I'll do that calculation

Comment: later if no one else does something equivalent/more instructive in the interim.

Comment: @AlexYoucis It's been a while, I'd be interested in seeing that computation worked out here.

Comment: Oh jeeze, I forgot about this and haven't checked math.se in a while. I will try and do it soon. Sorry :(

Comment: @AlexYoucis : I'll be interested me too if you have some time :-)